# Send simple data from one phone to another

Tags: tcp, nfc

I want to send four to five integers and a string from one phone to another using NFC, and I want also to receive data like that.

I searched the web and I found out that it's pretty easy to download data from a simple text file placed on the web. However, uploading is harder, and seriously, I think it would be faster to send the data from my phone to another user's phone than to send data from my phone to a server and have that user download the data from that server.

In what way can I share such simple data between two phones?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is. Though you still need to make sure that the phones know each others' ip-addresses, and you're not likely to achieve that without using a server of some sort.

Regarding "uploading is harder", ummm. If you think it would be easier to send the data between the two phones directly, you're wrong. There might be all kinds of firewalls blocking inbound connections on your telephony provider's network, for a start.

Uploading data to a server is not "hard", you just need to write a server program to handle it. You will need one anyway, just to pass the ip-addresses between the phones to set up a direct connection.

If I were you, I'd start with writing a simple server, and maybe just upload the adresses of the phones to it. (Of course, then you have the added complexity of having to figure out how to get the ip address from the phone's OS, which may or may not be nontrivial.)

However, whichever route you take, I'd recommend that you send your data over HTTP/ port 80. Less trouble with firewalls that way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one method is called [Near Field Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication)